# How to change this property to show % value in front end using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my class I have this property:

```
public decimal Percentage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

This value is displaying as a decimal.  Something like this:

```
-0.0214444
```

I need to show it something like this:

```
-2.14444
```

How can I change to this format in my property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply it by 100.

```
<%= myObject.Percentage * 100 %>
```

You can round it to a smaller number of decimal places:

```
<%= Math.Round(myObject.Percentage * 100, 3) %>
```

Another way:

```
<%= string.Format("Percentage is {0:0.0%}", myObject.Percentage) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "P" format string to add the percent sign. You can create another property to wrap it or just get Percentage and then call ToString.

```
public decimal Percentage { get; set; }

public string FormattedPercentage 
{ 
    get { return Percentage.ToString("P"); }
}
```